# Error: print image_to_string(image)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy implementado un algoritmo de reconocimiento de imágenes con pytesseract

```
import pytesseract
import sys
import argparse
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
from subprocess import check_output

path = "captcha.png"
def resolve(path):
    print("Resampling the Image")
    check_output(['convert', path, '-resample', '600', path])
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))

if __name__=="__main__":
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument('path',help = 'Captcha file path')
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    path = args.path
    print('Resolving Captcha')
    captcha_text = resolve(path)
    print('Extracted Text',captcha_text)
```

Pero el compilador de anaconda me lanza el siguiente error

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py",
>   line 153
>       print image_to_string(image)
>                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ya descargue pytesseract y tesseract lo importe, tesseract lo agregue dentro de las variables de entorno y aparece el mismo error. ¿que puede ser?

Comment: El error pareciera deberse a que estás usando un `pytesseract` para python 2x en un entorno de python 3x.

Comment: Si se puede utilizar en python 3.x pero con la ultima version de pytesser
utilice este comando en la cmd pip install -U git+https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract.git

Comment: El tema es que `pytesseract` está usando Anaconda, por el error, este archivo `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py` tiene esta instrucción `print image_to_string(image)` que es sintacticamente incorrecta en python 3x.